# Clean map using Angular DrawingManager

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

I'm using angular-google-maps in my app and using the directive  for drawing a Polyline.

All works fine but now i need to be able to create a button that clean the all lines drawn.

I do not find anything related to this in the API Documentation.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

At least I could find a solution.

I could guess that once a shape is completed, the event 'overlaycomplete' fires and then you can take the generated object into a global array, so when you wish to clear all shapes from the Map, yo just iterate over the global array and invoke setmap(null).

Here is the event:

```
overlaycomplete: function (dm, name, scope, objs) {
                _self.dm_overlays.push( objs );
                _self.drawingManagerOptions = { drawingMode: null };
            }
```

As you can see, I put the object in the array **dm_overlays**.

The function to clear the shapes from map is:

```
for ( var idx=0; idx < _self.dm_overlays.length; idx++ ) {
                _self.dm_overlays[idx][0].overlay.setMap(null);
            }
```

I hope this can help.